# C++ Problem with mixing composition and inheritance

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance, composition

I have to make a program for university and I'm having trouble using an object as an atribute for my "class player {}". The object I have to use inherits from a parent object and has one sibling : "gun : machinegun", and "gun : pistol".

I understand composition's basics, but I can't figure out how to implement this.

For example:

```
class player {protected: gun p; };
class gun {protected: int amunition;};
class pistol : public gun {};
```

Then when I create players, each player should have one of the posible guns; but I don't know how to do this.

I couldn't find information on internet, because the examples don't use a subclass as atribute; I think the soultion would be mix an "if" with new machinegun or new pistol, but I'm not sure.

I also tryed to use a pointer in the argument instead of instanciating an object, and then asign a new within an if; but It didn't compile, but maybe because there was another error. If someone could give me some advice, he would save me ours of debugging.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A gun is not necessarily an attribute of a player.    The ability to have a gun is (at least, as far as your model is concerned) a capability of the player, and that is independent of type of gun.

You're on the right track with using a pointer, but clearly have done something wrong.  Without code, nobody can advise what you have done wrong.

I'd represent the ability to have a gun using a pointer and set up `gun` as a polymorphic base.    That allows a `player` to refer to any type of `gun`.    It would also be necessary to provide some operation which allows a `player` to gain ownership of a `gun`.

```
 class gun
 {
      public:

          gun(int a = 0) : ammunition(a) {};
          virtual void fire() {--ammunition;};
      private:
          int ammunition;
 };

 class pistol : public gun
 {
      public:

          pistol(int a = 0) : gun(a) {};
          virtual void fire() {gun::fire();  gun::fire();};   // fire two rounds from a pistol
 };

 class player
 {
      public:

            player(gun *g = NULL) : p (g) {};

            void addGun(gun *g) { p = g;};

            void shoot() {p->fire();};
      private:

         gun *p;
 };

 int main()
 {
      pistol pistol(100);
      player gun_nut;
      gun_nut.addGun(&pistol);;
      gun_nut.shoot(); 
 }
```

The above is rather static, and all the objects will simply cease to exist when `main()` returns.   If you want to dynamically create guns and players in your program, consider using smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<gun>` rather than `gun *`).   This allows dynamically creating guns of various types, adding them to a player, and the guns will cease to exist when no longer need.

Obviously, you'll need to provide other operations and error checking (e.g. a gun should not fire if out of ammunition, a player with no gun should not fire a gun, etc etc).   Also note that I've avoided using protected members - it would often not be necessary if you provide suitable member functions that access private members in a controlled manner.

Comment: Tanks I will try do adapt my code to your sugestion, If It works I will let you know.
I didn't post any other code, because there isn't; I got stuck there and the methods where just shoot -- ++.

Answer (score 0):

first of all if your code look like this

```
class player {protected: gun p; };
class gun {protected: int amunition;};
class pistol : public gun {};
```

or if you don't have a forward declaration the compiler will return an error when compile the correct declaration is :

```
class gun {protected: int amunition;};

class player {protected: gun p; };

class pistol : public gun {};

int main(){
    player p;
}
```

in addiction of this for public purpose you would not be able to use the object of gun on your class player
because is protected you will need to have a method on public are of your class or move the object of gun there.

example could be:

```
class player 
{
    protected: gun p; 
    public:
    const gun& get_gun(){
        return p;
    }    
};
or

class player{
    public:
    gun p;
};
```

Comment: Yes, the code I posted (I forgot to mention that) was to illustrate the problem with the composition; all the other methods and such where not posted because It would make the question messier.

Comment: But do you have any suggestion with my problem, I don't know how to instantiate the guns.

Comment: as could seen your gun has default constructor and as your gun object is not a pointer you could use it as-is, but I would like to know something, do you have any error when compile? at least try to show us how the gun constructor work.. and is good idea to check @peter solution seem that meet your need.